# Trying to implement Array methods for a calculator

Tags: javascript

let displayResult = ''

For the params....I have

```
operatorArray = ['+']
operandsArray = ['24','9']
```

As I have attached my problem , the final display value is not changing, it is stuck at 0. What do I have to do ?

```js
function Compute(operatorArray,...operandsArray) {
 let firstOperand = Number(operandsArray[0]);
 let secondOperand = Number(operandsArray[1]);

  
  if (operatorArray.includes("+"))
  {
     let result = firstOperand + secondOperand ;
     displayResult = result;
     }
 return; 
}
```

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: My bad didn't know images were not allowed. I was trying to be helpful.

Comment: Why are you using rest parameter in a parameter that gets an array? Rest parameter is used to group each separate params into an array. In `Compute` function, operandsArray is `[ [ 24, 9 ] ]`. operandsArray[0] is `[ 24, 9 ]` and [1] is `undefined`.

Comment: Please present the calling code.  Passing an array as `operandsArray`, then using the spread operator, then indexing will produce NaNs

Comment: I learned that rest params can be used to insert an entire array into a function argument, so why not

Comment: Okay and I removed the spread operator, that doesn't solve the question. How should it be called to access the elements in the array inside the function ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code.

First, you're using rest parameter which acceps an array. Rest parameter is used to group each separate parameters into an array. However, since you're passing an array, rest parameter creates an 2d array, like this: `[ [ 24, 9 ] ]`.

So you need to remove `...` from `operandsArray` param.

Second, you're trying to access a variable in the calling scope inside a function.

Functions have an independent scope in where the function is defined.

So in your case, you're trying to access `displayResult` that is in the function calling scope. So the function is outside the scope, and trying to set it actually creates another `displayResult` inside the function scope(more specifically, inside `if` scope). So in the end, the `Compute` function does not do anything.

In this case, you should return the `result` value. Then tou can assign the function result to a variable, do `console.log`, and many.

So the code would be:

```js
function Compute(operatorArray, operandsArray) {
  let result = 0;
  let firstOperand = Number(operandsArray[0]);
  let secondOperand = Number(operandsArray[1]);
  if (operatorArray.includes("+"))
  {
    result = firstOperand + secondOperand 
  }
  return result;
}
```

And call it like this:

```js
displayResult = Compute(operatorArray, operandsArray)
```

Comment: Yes, I had to call displayResult like that to get it work - so that is due to scoping. Thanks again for the detailed teaching.